# What is difference between Post Tool and Index Handlers?

Tags: json, curl, solr, lucene

I have a JSON documents which needs to be indexed in Solr. The document looks like this:

```
{  
   "id":"1",
   "prop":null,
   "path":"1.parent",
   "_childDocuments_":[  
      {  
         "id":"2",
         "path":"2.parent.child"
      }
   ]
}
```

It contains parent-child relationship structure denoted by `_childDocuments_` key.

When I insert the documents in Solr via Post Tool, i.e., `./bin/post -c coreName data.json` and query the Solr, then I get following response from Solr:

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/coreName/select?indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json'
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "indent":"on",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"1",
        "path":["1.parent"],
        "_childDocuments_.id":[2],
        "_childDocuments_.path":["2.parent.child"],
        "_version_":1566718833663672320}]
  }}
```

But when I try to insert the same JSON document via Index Handler, i.e., `curl` -

```
$ curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/coreName/update?commit=true" -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary "@1.json"
{"responseHeader":{"status":400,"QTime":56},"error":{"metadata":["error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException","root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],"msg":"Unknown command 'id' at [11]","code":400}}
```

I get `SolrException`. But if I put the JSON in array, then it shows another error, i.e.,

```
[{  
   "id":"1",
   "prop": null,
   "path":"1.parent",
   "_childDocuments_":[  
      {  
         "id":"2",
         "path":"2.parent.child"
      }
   ]
}]
```

Error:

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/coreName/update?commit=true' -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data "@/home/knoldus/practice/solr/1.json"
{"responseHeader":{"status":500,"QTime":3},"error":{"trace":"java.lang.NullPointerException\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory$AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessor.mapValueClassesToFieldType(AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory.java:370)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory$AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory.java:288)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory$1.processAdd(FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory.java:74)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:48)\n\tat org.apache.solr.update.processor.AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory$DefaultValueUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory.java:91)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader$SingleThreadedJsonLoader.handleAdds(JsonLoader.java:492)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader$SingleThreadedJsonLoader.processUpdate(JsonLoader.java:139)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader$SingleThreadedJsonLoader.load(JsonLoader.java:115)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader.load(JsonLoader.java:78)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:97)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:68)\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:166)\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2306)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:658)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:464)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:345)\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:296)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\n","code":500}}
```

So, I have to remove `"prop": null` as well or make it an empty string, like this:

```
[{  
   "id":"1",
   "prop": "",
   "path":"1.parent",
   "_childDocuments_":[  
      {  
         "id":"2",
         "path":"2.parent.child"
      }
   ]
}]
```

After making these modifications, when I insert the JSON doc. in Solr via `curl`, then it works fine.

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/coreName/update?commit=true' -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data "@/home/knoldus/practice/solr/1.json"
{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":851}}
```

And I get following response from Solr query:

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/coreName/select?indent=on&q=*:*&wt=json'
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "indent":"on",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"2",
        "path":["2.parent.child"]},
      {
        "id":"1",
        "path":["1.parent"],
        "_version_":1566719240059224064}]
  }}
```

But here again I see a difference that `_childDocuments_` have been indexed as separate documents.

So, I have following questions on two different methods of data indexing in Solr:

1. Why Post Tool `./bin/post` does not index `_childDocuments_` separately like Request Handler `/update`?
2. Why Request Handler `/update` requires JSON document to be wrapped in array?
3. And last, why Request Handler `/update` cannot handle `null` values whereas Post Tool can?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostTool is just some small java utility that reads the input you give to it, and sends it to Solr. It is not running inside Solr. I have not looked but I am pretty sure:

1. it does not detect *childDocuments* as a special value and sends it just like any other nested json
2. as explained [in the docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers), /update requires the array, you can send individual json doc to /update/json/docs
3. PostTool is converting the null to either "" and just ignoring the field

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I got the way of indexing one doc via index handler, but why `null` values are not accepted via index handler, that is not mentioned in documentation ?